# Как привязать активный чекбокс и блок внутри которого он находится?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Сейчас я вывожу в одном блоке количество выбранных элементов, в другом `label` выбранных элементов по порядку, не сортируя.

```
Выбрано: 2
Названия: Тонна , Прямая
```

Нужно чтобы сортировалась, примерно в таком виде:

```
Выбрано: 2
Единица измерения: Тонна 
Полярность: Прямая
```

т.е. есть два блока -
1) "**единицы измерения**" и "**килограммы**" "**тонны**"
2) "**Полярность**" и "**обратная**" "**прямая**".
Нужно чтобы в блок "**единицы измерения**" попадали только "**килограммы**" и "**тонны**", а в блок "**полярность**" попадали только "**обратная**" и "**прямая**"

А пустой блок (например если чекбоксы в "**Полярность**" не активные) не отображался вообще.

Эти названия ("**Единицы измерения**", "**Полярность**") строятся динамически. Их может быть больше, они могут быть другие.

Я получаю эти значения(**Единица измерения**, **Полярность**), перебираю их, но как связать активные чекбоксы и название для блока с чекбоксами не знаю. Вот пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vooyrs1/6/)

Понимаю что при изменении значения чекбокса можно проверять каждый элемент `.ctf--b-filt-c-item`: и если есть выбранные чекбоксы, то брать текст из элемента `.ctf--b-filt-c-head` и после него через запятую выводите все лейблы выбранных чекбоксов. Но не пойму как составить условие, или например как взять текст из элемента только того `.ctf--b-filt-c-head` который выбран

```js
var label = $('.ctf--b-filt-check-list label'),
  checkbox = $('.ctf--b-filt-check-list :checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var checked = checkbox.filter(':checked');
    $('#count').html('Выбрано: ' + checked.length);
    var labelText = checked.map(function(i, el) {
      return label.filter('[for="' + el.id + '"]').text();
    }).get().join(',');
    
    $('#unit').html('Названия: ' + labelText);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ctf--b-filt-c-item open ctf--b-filt-c-item--active">
  <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-head"><span class="b-txt">Единица измерения:</span></div>
  <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-body" style="display: block;">
    <div class="ctf--b-wpr-scr">
      <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ctf--b-filt-check-list--double">        
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_0_0" value="11770">
          <label for="idchkk_2_0_0">
            <i></i>
            Килограмм
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_0_1" value="11771">
          <label for="idchkk_2_0_1">
            <i></i>
            Тонна
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ctf--b-filt-check-list--double">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="ctf--b-filt-c-item open ctf--b-filt-c-item--active">
  <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-head"><span class="b-txt">Полярность:</span></div>
  <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-body" style="display: block;">
    <div class="ctf--b-wpr-scr">
      <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ">
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_2_0" value="11773">
          <label for="idchkk_2_2_0">
            <i></i>
            Обратная
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_2_1" value="11776">
          <label for="idchkk_2_2_1">
            <i></i>
            Прямая
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="count"></div>
<div id="unit"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменение кода заключается в применении селектора для групп, и фильтрации дочерних элементов для каждой найденной группы

```js
var unit = $('.ctf--b-filt-c-head span').text().split(':');
checkbox = $('.ctf--b-filt-check-list :checkbox').on('change', function() {

 $('#unit').html('');
 var checked = checkbox.filter(':checked');
 $('#count').html('Выбрано: ' + checked.length);

 var blocks = $('.ctf--b-filt-c-item');
 $.each(blocks,function(block_number,block_content) {

 var labelText = checked.map(function(i, el) {
   return $(block_content).find('.ctf--b-filt-check-list label').filter('[for="' + el.id + '"]').text();
  }).get().join(',').trim();

  var response = labelText;
  if ((response)&&(response!==',')) {
   $('#unit').append( $(block_content).find('.ctf--b-filt-c-head span').text() + response);
   $('#unit').append('<br>');
  }
    });        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ctf--b-filt-c-item open ctf--b-filt-c-item--active">
  <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-head"><span class="b-txt">Единица измерения:</span></div>
  <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-body" style="display: block;">
    <div class="ctf--b-wpr-scr">
      <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ctf--b-filt-check-list--double">        
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_0_0" value="11770">
          <label for="idchkk_2_0_0">
            <i></i>
            Килограмм
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_0_1" value="11771">
          <label for="idchkk_2_0_1">
            <i></i>
            Тонна
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ctf--b-filt-check-list--double">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="ctf--b-filt-c-item open ctf--b-filt-c-item--active">
  <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-head"><span class="b-txt">Полярность:</span></div>
  <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-body" style="display: block;">
    <div class="ctf--b-wpr-scr">
      <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ">
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_2_0" value="11773">
          <label for="idchkk_2_2_0">
            <i></i>
            Обратная
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_2_1" value="11776">
          <label for="idchkk_2_2_1">
            <i></i>
            Прямая
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="count"></div>
<div id="unit"></div>
```